# Calculating light for custom geometry in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've created a custom geometry and I've used `geometry.computeFaceNormals()` to get the lighting right. So far so good.

The problem comes when I animate the geometry. In the animation loop I call again `geometry.computeFaceNormals()` but the faces' lighting doesn't change.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z6td0srh/4/) with the example:

Comment: Do you want flat shading? https://jsfiddle.net/z6td0srh/5/ or smooth shading? https://jsfiddle.net/z6td0srh/6/

Comment: Thanks a lot @WestLangley! I was looking for flat shading. Feel free to elaborate your comment and make it an answer so I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating the vertices of your geometry, so typically, your normals must also be updated for the shading to be correct.

However, since you want flat shading, there is another solution.

`MeshPhongMaterial` generates flat shading using the OES_standard_derivatives extension. This means that geometry normals do not have to be specified or updated when vertices change.

All you have to do is use the following pattern, and flat shading will "just work" -- provided the extension is supported.

```
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
    color: 0xFFFFFF,
    shading: THREE.FlatShading
} );
```

three.js r.80